# Combine Multiple ID's as the variable SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, concatenation, inner-join

Writing a report and having an issue I was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction

I have 2 tables `tbl_RegisterMain_Holding` and `LyndseyCouncils`

In the `tbl_RegisterMain_Holding` there is 12 columns that have `LA_id_Build (1 -12)` in them

I want to be able to use the variable (5,12,23) = `‘East Midlands’`  as the variable that will bring back any rows that have any of those numbers in.

Here is what the data looks like in the LyndseyCouncils table

```
LA_ID   Listings
5       East Midlands
12      East Midlands
23      East Midlands
15      East of England
21      East of England
25      East of England
79      London
80      London
201     London
3       London and the Home Counties
11      London and the Home Counties
13      London and the Home Counties
352     North East
365     North East
372     North East
```

Here is my Query I’m working on

```
SELECT rm.Email,Forname,Surname,lc.listings
FROM dbo.tbl_RegisterMain_Holding AS rm
INNER JOIN [dbo].[LyndseyCouncils] AS lc
ON rm.LA_ID_live = lc.LA_ID
WHERE 
(rm.LA_ID_BUILD1 = @COUNCIL or rm.LA_ID_BUILD2 = @COUNCIL or rm.LA_ID_BUILD3 = @COUNCIL 
or rm.LA_ID_BUILD4 = @COUNCIL 
or rm.LA_ID_BUILD5 = @COUNCIL or rm.LA_ID_BUILD6 = @COUNCIL 
or rm.LA_ID_BUILD7 = @COUNCIL or rm.LA_ID_BUILD8 = @COUNCIL or rm.LA_ID_BUILD9 = @COUNCIL 
or rm.LA_ID_BUILD10 = @COUNCIL 
or rm.LA_ID_BUILD11 = @COUNCIL or rm.LA_ID_BUILD12 = @COUNCIL)
```

This would work if I was using just one La_ID but because I’m using multiple LA_ID It should be IN ()
But have no idea how I would write that,
Maybe I’m going about this in the wrong way.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `... where @COUNCIL  IN (rm.LA_ID_BUILD1, rm.LA_ID_BUILD2,   ... rm.LA_ID_BUILD12)`

Comment: you can make a table variable, then join in main table and filter easily.

Comment: `WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT null FROM  LyndseyCouncils lc2 WHERE lc2.Listings='East Midlands' AND lc2.LA_ID IN (rm.LA_ID_BUILD1, rm.LA_ID_BUILD2, ... rm.LA_ID_BUILD12)))` I suppose

Comment: Jarlh if i declare the variable @council like this it wont work

Comment: Serg your where clause worked for this issue thanks allot